# Make downloads in wget utilize full bandwith

Tags: download, wget

I am using an app called WSUS to download updates for Windows and Office. It works fine, but the problem is that I am on a time-based connection and wget (what WSUS utilizes to download files) does not use my max bandwith, which I use when downloading a file using IDM when it connects and downloads parts of the file at the same time.

Is there a way to do something like this in wget? Is there another utility I can use to rename as wget which uses the same commands and maxes out my bandwith? Can I even use IDM's CMD to do this?

I have already checked out other questions on this site and on Google but nothing seems to work as they only seem to suggest things like WinHTTrack but they don't work in the current scenario.

I am using Windows 10 x64 with a 3G Modem.

I appreciate any replies. Thanks.

PS:- I am downloading from Microsoft Servers. They max out my connection using IDM. I don't think a server limit is the problem.

Comment: I would like to note that you will only download as fast as the server let's you even if you have a high bandwidth.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I have updated my question. I don't think it has anything to do with a server-side speed limit. Thanks for your answer anyway!